# Any workaround for the use of the word 'new' in IE8?

Tags: internet-explorer-8

Error in Ie8 when using the word 'new' in your object. I must use this word because I'm using 
I'm trying to do something like that:

```
$(e.items.new).each(function(index) {
    console.log(index)
});
```

In ie8 i'm getting this error: "Expected identifier". I think because of the use of 'new' save words.

Any chance to workaround? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not just IE8: `new` is a [reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words) and it shouldn't be used as a variable or key name in any browser.

You can use reserved words as an object key if you use quotes when defining it and the bracket notation when retrieving the value: `e.items[ 'new' ]`.

Comment: +1: the best solution is not to use reserved keywords like this. But if you must, then the `['name']` syntax is the only option.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `[]` notation, i.e. in your case `e.items['new']` instead of `e.items.new`

This is equivalent to `e.items.new` except the fact that the JavaScript engine never sees the property name as anything but a string - so it can be anything no matter if it's a valid identifier or not  (`new` is a reserved keyword in JavaScript so it can't be used as an identifier).